# Custom Error Page Being Sent With Ajax Response in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

Why would the custom error page be sent with the ajax response below when an error occurs?

Response

```
{"Errors":["An error has occurred and we have been notified.  We are sorry for the inconvenience."]}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Error</title>
```

Web.Config

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error" mode="On"></customErrors>
```

BaseController.cs

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

                var validatorModel = new ValidatorModel();

                if (filterContext.Exception is AriesException && !((AriesException)filterContext.Exception).Visible && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                {
                    validatorModel.Errors.Add(this.Resource("UnknownError"));
                }
                else
                {
                    validatorModel.Errors.Add(filterContext.Exception.Message);
                }

                response.Clear();
                response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                response.Write(validatorModel.ToJson());
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            else if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }

            if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                SiteLogger.Write(filterContext.Exception);
            }
        }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added response.End(); and it worked.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is still having this issue, I found a slightly cleaner solution:

```
if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
        //non-ajax exception handling code here
}
else
{
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

dsomuah's solution is nice, but has to be added to each controller that serves Ajax requests. We took it a step further by globally registering the following action filter:

```
public class HandleAjaxErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although dsomuah's code could easily go into your controller base class, as many projects already implement for various reasons, it's nice to see this method listed here. +1